# Flutter TableCalendar: how to change day selected pattern

Tags: flutter, calendar

When I select a day in TableCalendar, the output of _onDaySelected is (example)

2021-04-20 **12:00:00.000Z**

My problem is that my API returns a date like '2021-04-20', and after parse '2021-04-20 **00:00:00.0000**'

Is it possible to change the date format to make them the same?

Answer (score 0):

The "Z" in the Date of the TableCalendar stands for "Zero", meaning it's the UTC time which is retrieved.

To fix your problem you should either format the date coming from your API to the UTC time, or the date retrieved from your TableCalendar to the format you used in your parsing method.

If you have a lot of Date manipulations to do, you could consider using the [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) library.

Comment: FDuhen, how can I change the date retrieved from TableCalendar to the format '2021-04-20 00:00:00.0000'?